# Room Junction Pojo

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room

I try to fetch N:M database entities in a pojo.

Here are the entities:

Person:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "person_table",
    indices = [Index("person_id")]
)
class Person() {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id")
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

Car:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "car_table",
    indices = [Index("car_id")]
)
class Car() {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "car_id")
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

And the junction entity:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "person_car_join",
    primaryKeys = ["fk_person_id", "fk_car_id"],
    indices = [
        Index("fk_person_id"),
        Index("fk_car_id")
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Person::class,
            childColumns = arrayOf("fk_person_id"),
            parentColumns = arrayOf("person_id")
        ), ForeignKey(
            entity = Car::class,
            childColumns = arrayOf("fk_car_id"),
            parentColumns = arrayOf("car_id")
        )
    ]
)
class PersonCarJoin(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_person_id") var fkPersonId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_car_id") var fkCarId: Long
)
```

This is my Pojo:

```
class PersonWithCarsPojo {

    @Embedded
    lateinit var person: Person

    @Relation(
        entityColumn = "car_id",
        parentColumn = "person_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            PersonCarJoin::class,
            parentColumn = "fk_person_id",
            entityColumn = "fk_car_id"
        )
    )
    var cars: List<Car> = arrayListOf()
}
```

And I try to fetch them with this query:

```
@Query(
    """
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        person_table;
    """
)
fun getAllPersonsWithCars(): LiveData<List<PersonWithCarsPojo>>
```

But I only get all persons with only 1 car in the cars list. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that you are adding the relationships?

Or do you have at least **version 2.2.0** of the respective Room libraries, in which `associateBy` and `@Junction` were added. [Version 2.2.0 - October 9, 2019](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3)

Based upon your code (but using Java rather than Kotlin) then the following :-

```
    mPersonCarsDao = mRTDB.personCarsDao();
    mPersonCarsDao.insertPeople(
            new Person("Fred"),
            new Person("Jane"),
            new Person("Anne")
    );
    mPersonCarsDao.insertCars(
            new Car("A"),
            new Car("B"),
            new Car("C")
    );
    mPersonCarsDao.insertPersonCarJoins(
            new PersonCarJoin(1,2), // Fred -> B
            new PersonCarJoin(1,3), // Fred -> C
            new PersonCarJoin(2,1), // Jane -> A
            new PersonCarJoin(2,3), // Jane -> C
            new PersonCarJoin(3,3) // Anne -> C
    );

    List<PersonWithCarsPojo> personWithCarsPojos = mPersonCarsDao.getAllPeopleWithCars();
    for (PersonWithCarsPojo pwcp: personWithCarsPojos) {
        for (Car c: pwcp.cars) {
            Log.d("PWCPINFO","Person is " + pwcp.getPerson().getName() + " Car is " + c.getCar());
        }
    }
```

Outputs :-

```
2019-10-09 07:22:40.163 D/PWCPINFO: Person is Fred Car is B
2019-10-09 07:22:40.163 D/PWCPINFO: Person is Fred Car is C
2019-10-09 07:22:40.163 D/PWCPINFO: Person is Jane Car is A
2019-10-09 07:22:40.163 D/PWCPINFO: Person is Jane Car is C
2019-10-09 07:22:40.163 D/PWCPINFO: Person is Anne Car is C
```

PersonCarsDao being :-

```
@Dao
public interface PersonCarsDao {

    @Insert
    long[] insertPeople(Person... people);

    @Insert
    long insertPerson(Person person);

    @Insert
    long[] insertCars(Car... cars);

    @Insert
    long insertCar(Car car);

    @Insert
    long insertPersonCarJoin(PersonCarJoin personCarJoin);

    @Insert
    long[] insertPersonCarJoins(PersonCarJoin... personCarJoins);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM car_table")
    List<Car> getAllCars();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table")
    List<Person> getAllPeople();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM car_table WHERE car_id = :car_id")
    Car getCarById(long car_id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE person_id = :person_id")
    Person getPersonById(long person_id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table")
    List<PersonWithCarsPojo> getAllPeopleWithCars();

}
```

---

Additional (with Kotlin)

The following is the full code of the above but in Kotlin and it works.

**Person.kt** (added personName column)

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "person_table",
    indices = [Index("person_id")]
)
class Person() {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id")
    var id: Long = 0

    var personName: String = ""
}
```

**Car.kt** (added carName column)

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "car_table",
    indices = [Index("car_id")]
)
class Car {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "car_id")
    var id: Long = 0

    var carName: String = ""
}
```

**PersonCarJoin.kt** (unchanged)

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "person_car_join",
    primaryKeys = ["fk_person_id", "fk_car_id"],
    indices = [
        Index("fk_person_id"),
        Index("fk_car_id")
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Person::class,
            childColumns = arrayOf("fk_person_id"),
            parentColumns = arrayOf("person_id")
        ), ForeignKey(
            entity = Car::class,
            childColumns = arrayOf("fk_car_id"),
            parentColumns = arrayOf("car_id")
        )
    ]
)
class PersonCarJoin(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_person_id") var fkPersonId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_car_id") var fkCarId: Long
)
```

**PersonWithCarsPojo** (unchanged)

```
class PersonWithCarsPojo {

    @Embedded
    lateinit var person: Person

    @Relation(
        entityColumn = "car_id",
        parentColumn = "person_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            PersonCarJoin::class,
            parentColumn = "fk_person_id",
            entityColumn = "fk_car_id"
        )
    )
    var cars: List<Car> = arrayListOf()
}
```

**PersonCarDoa** (created but contains your getAllPersonsWithCars)

```
@Dao
interface PersonCarDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertPerson(person: Person): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertpeople(vararg People: Person)

    @Insert
    fun insertCar(car: Car): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertCars(vararg cars: Car)

    @Insert
    fun insertPersonCarJoin(personCarJoin: PersonCarJoin): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table")
    fun getAllPersonsWithCars(): List<PersonWithCarsPojo>
}
```

**AppDatabase.kt** (created)

```
@Database(version = 1, entities =  [Person::class,Car::class,PersonCarJoin::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun personCarDao(): PersonCarDao
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java,"personcardb")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        val personCarDao = db.personCarDao()

        val person = Person()
        person.personName = "Fred"
        personCarDao.insertPerson(person)
        person.personName = "Jane"
        personCarDao.insertPerson(person)
        person.personName = "Anne"
        personCarDao.insertPerson(person)

        val car = Car()
        car.carName = "A"
        personCarDao.insertCar(car)
        car.carName = "B"
        personCarDao.insertCar(car)
        car.carName = "C"
        personCarDao.insertCar(car)

        val pcj1 = PersonCarJoin(1,2)
        personCarDao.insertPersonCarJoin(pcj1)
        val pcj2 = PersonCarJoin(1,3)
        personCarDao.insertPersonCarJoin(pcj2)
        val pcj3 = PersonCarJoin(2,1)
        personCarDao.insertPersonCarJoin(pcj3)
        val pcj4 = PersonCarJoin(2,3)
        personCarDao.insertPersonCarJoin(pcj4)
        val pcj5 = PersonCarJoin(3,3)
        personCarDao.insertPersonCarJoin(pcj5)

        val theList: List<PersonWithCarsPojo> = personCarDao.getAllPersonsWithCars()
        for (pwc: PersonWithCarsPojo in theList) {
            for(c: Car in pwc.cars) {
                Log.d("PWCINFO","Person is " + pwc.person.personName + " Car is " + c.carName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Result (log from final for loop)

```
2019-10-09 20:25:08.364 D/PWCINFO: Person is Fred Car is B
2019-10-09 20:25:08.364 D/PWCINFO: Person is Fred Car is C
2019-10-09 20:25:08.364 D/PWCINFO: Person is Jane Car is A
2019-10-09 20:25:08.364 D/PWCINFO: Person is Jane Car is C
2019-10-09 20:25:08.364 D/PWCINFO: Person is Anne Car is C
```

**As you can see for the 3 Persons and 3 cars but 5 outputs (Fred has 2 cars, as does Jane while Anne has just 1 car)**

Comment: Strange. And yes im sure. I already saved the internal database to my pc and had a look in it. I also realized, that Person with ID 1 has only the Car with ID 1 in his list, Person with ID 2 has only Car with ID 2 in his list (although the join does not exist). Any ideas?

Comment: @Prexx, uhhm same value for Person and the Car sounds like you may be adding to the PersonCarJoin using only the Person id, rather than the Person Id and the Car id. In which case whatever Cars you think you are adding you would only ever add the 1 car per person. Perhaps try using the Dao as above (copy and then use the Convert to Koitlin option) and try replicating the example given in the answer (note after adding the Dao to the @Database).

Comment: As I said I saved the app database to my pc and checked the values. PersonTable, CarTable and PersonCarJoinTable looks fine and all ids are stored correctly. Maybe it's a Kotlin bug?

Comment: @Prexx, I've added a crude Kotlin example that works. So not a bug unless it's to do with LiveData which the example doesn't use.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Strange anyway. I'll have a deeper look into that. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I set up a whole new project and just copy&pasted the Kotlin snippets and have the same behavior: Each person has only one car in the list. Could you please post the dependencies or upload the project to git or somewhere else? Very frustrating. :/ Thank you!!

Comment: @Prexx in GitHub as [PersonCar](https://github.com/Mike-j-t-laptop/PersonCar)

Comment: Finally... the dependencies "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.0" and "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0" were missing. Thanks a lot!! Now I can sleep peacefully again.

Comment: @Prexx `associateBy` and `@Junction` were introduced with 2.2.0, will update answer accordingly.